# Importing huge JSON file into DB

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, stream, psql

I have a 4GB JSON file that I need to import into a DB. The JSON is:

```
{
  "transport_metadata": {
    "id": "81b18379105fa9626fde73b99bfa6cbac4d3618d",
    "source_system": "test",
    "build_version": "0.1.1",
    "schema_version": "schema_x",
    "creation_time": ""
  },
  "payload": {
    "data": [
      {...},{...},{...}
    ]
  }
}
```

The only part I need to save in the Database is the array inside data.

I've tried JSONStream library with Postgres and Knex, using transactions, but apparently, JSONStream doesn't deal very good with huge amounts of data and goes out of memory (which shouldn't, because it uses streams.. profiling shows that a stream.write is 'leaking' memory(?).

I tried the PSQL copy function, but could not import only the `.payload.data` into a temporary table `create unlogged table _import_jsonb (doc jsonb);`

I'm not completely sure what would be the best approach, do someone sees a better implementation approach for this?

Comment: Is node/js mandatory or any tool suffices as long as it gets the task done?

Comment: Could you parse out the part you need with jq first?

Comment: Have you tried gridFS?

Comment: Any tool is enough, I will check jq and gridFS!

Comment: Can you load whole file into temporary table and then use built-in functions and operators to extract what you need and save it in more permanent table? Assuming database is local to that file, otherwise I can see issue uploading 4GB.